# IText Add Certificate infos to Appearence signature field

Tags: java, itext, digital-signature, signature

I am trying to make a digital signature (PKCS12 file) using iText, but I cannot find how to have an appearance with the information of the certificate used for the signature.

**UPDATE 1 :**
the following test class allows you to sign a document using a p12 certificate and impose a visual on the PDF document:

```
package ma.sigital.dsp.prosigngateway.service;


import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.Security;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.util.Date;

import com.itextpdf.text.Rectangle;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;

import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Image;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfSignatureAppearance;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfSignatureAppearance.RenderingMode;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfStamper;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.BouncyCastleDigest;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.DigestAlgorithms;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.ExternalDigest;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.MakeSignature;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.MakeSignature.CryptoStandard;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.PrivateKeySignature;

public class Test {
public static final String DEST = "B:/Hash-et-Reconstitution/tmp/SIGNED-Doc_test.pdf";

public static final String KEYSTORE = "C:/lp7command/tools/certificate.p12";
public static final String SRC = "B:/Hash-et-Reconstitution/tmp/Doc_test.pdf";
public static final String IMG = "C:/Repo_LP7/logo-cire.png";

public static final char[] PASSWORD = "123456".toCharArray();

public static final String[] RESULT_FILES = new String[] {
        "signature_appearance_1.pdf",
        "signature_appearance_2.pdf",
        "signature_appearance_3.pdf",
        "signature_appearance_4.pdf"
};

public void sign(String src, String name, String dest,
                 Certificate[] chain, PrivateKey pk,
                 String digestAlgorithm, String provider,
                 CryptoStandard subfilter,
                 String reason, String location, RenderingMode renderingMode,
                 Image image)
        throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException, DocumentException {
    // Creating the reader and the stamper
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(dest);
    PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, os, '\0');
    // Creating the appearance
    PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.getSignatureAppearance();
    appearance.setReason(reason);
    appearance.setLocation(location);
    appearance.setVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(200, 100, 600, 5),2,"sig");
    appearance.setLayer2Text("Signed on " + new Date().toString());

    appearance.setRenderingMode(renderingMode);
    appearance.setSignatureGraphic(image);
    // Creating the signature
    PrivateKeySignature pks = new PrivateKeySignature(pk, digestAlgorithm, provider);
    ExternalDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();
    MakeSignature.signDetached(appearance, digest, pks, chain, null, null, null, 0, subfilter);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException, DocumentException {
    BouncyCastleProvider provider = new BouncyCastleProvider();
    Security.addProvider(provider);
    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
    ks.load(new FileInputStream(KEYSTORE), PASSWORD);
    String alias = (String)ks.aliases().nextElement();
    PrivateKey pk = (PrivateKey) ks.getKey(alias, PASSWORD);
    Certificate[] chain = ks.getCertificateChain(alias);
    Image image = Image.getInstance(IMG);
    Test app = new Test();

    app.sign(SRC, "Signature1", String.format(DEST, 3), chain, pk,
            DigestAlgorithms.SHA256, provider.getName(), CryptoStandard.CMS,
            "Appearance 3", "Ghent", RenderingMode.GRAPHIC_AND_DESCRIPTION, image);

}
}
```

Comment: what exactly you meen signature? Is some signature as image, electronic signature, or using password to file?

Comment: I mean digital signature using PKCS12 certificate.

Comment: **A** Please share your pivotal code for signing with iText. **B** Is the problem that you get no visualization at all? Or do you merely get a different one than you expected? **C** Which iText version are you using? A 7.0.x or 7.1.x? A 5.5.x? A 2.1.7?

Comment: A- I just shared the code used
B- The problem I encounter is that I can not find a solution to display the information (subject, DN ..) of the certificate used for the signature. The code I just shared just allows you to display a custom text in the signature area. My goal is to display the subject of the certificate used for signing
C- Regarding the iText version I use it is: 5.5.13.1

Comment: You explicitly set the layer 2 text (`setLayer2Text`). Have you checked what happens if you don't?

Comment: If I don't put setLayer2Text, I get the same visual but this time with the name of the signer. But still not the subject of the certificate

Comment: If you read your question once again, you'll see that you didn't mention that you want the full subject of the certificate instead of merely the common name of the subject (the name of the signer).

Comment: In my question i said information of certificate, it’s mean all the informations

Comment: If i don't put setLayer2Text properties, i got a label "Signed By " in English and in my case i want to have this label in french

Comment: @mkl I have another quick question PLEASE, if we use the remote signature (by calculating the hash of the original document in a server A and having it signed in a server B and integrate it into the original document afterwards), we can have the CN in the visual of the signature ? thank you very much for your usual help

Comment: *"In my question i said information of certificate, it’s mean all the informations"* - that's ridiculous, that would fill pages. Please simply get used to clearly stating what you are looking for.

Comment: Essentially, either you let iText create the text or you do it yourself (with `setLayer2Text`). In the former case you simply get what you already have observed, there is no pattern or localization to set. In the latter case, you can put anything you want into that text. As you have the whole certificate chain at hands, you can in particular can add any information from the signer certificate.

Comment: *"if we use the remote signature (by calculating the hash of the original document in a server A and having it signed in a server B and integrate it into the original document afterwards), we can have the CN in the visual of the signature ?"* - If you know the CN before signing on server A, sure, why not.

Comment: @mkl Thank you for your reply. So in case we don't have the certificate chain we can't get the CN? Basically if the certificate is in server B and not in server A, we cannot retrieve the certificate information from the signed hash for example?

Comment: The signature appearance is part of the *signed PDF data*. To have some specific information in it, therefore, your code on server A has to have that information *before* signing.

Comment: @mkl thank you very much for your help, it's very kind.  it's very kind